# Comparing char* with char

Tags: c, char, compare

I am working on a program where I get the name of a file from the input in a command line. I need to check if the input is a given character say "-" and work with the file according to this result, but I am not quite sure how to do it. The method I have tried, which seemed to logically make sense, of just checking if

```
argv[1] == "-";
```

always returns zero, even when I write "-" in the command input. What can I do?

Comment: Tag the language you're using...

Comment: If you are just comparing the first char, make it easy on yourself `if (*argv[1] == 'a')`

Comment: `argv[1]` is an address of a (null-terminated) array of characters. `"a"` is an address of another (null-terminated) array of characters. Those addresses are not equal.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: This will not serve OP's purpose, as it will return true for other strings as well (for example, `"ab"`).

Comment: And if you dereference the string `*(*(argv + 1))` you get what? `argv[1][0]`

Comment: @barakmanos Granted - that's why I said **If you are just comparing the first char**. For more than one char it obviously won't work.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Yes, I was saying it under the assumption that OP's intention is to assert that the input argument is the single character string `"a"`. I think it's a plausible assumption to make here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to write 
`strcmp(argv[1],"a")==0;`

in your example, you compared two pointers , not two strings. 
when compiling, the compiler declares "a" somewhere in the memory , then subsitute it in compile time with its memory address. since argv[1] can't really sit on the same byte with (temporary) "a" , the result is always false.
you need to iterate over the two strings and iterativly compare each character.
`strcmp` compares 2 strings and return 0 if they are equale in this exact manner.

for more info on `strcmp` : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

in order to handle multiple characters, you can place few if-else's :

```
if (strcmp(argv[1],"-")==0){
   minus_character_handling_function();
} else if (strcmp(argv[1],"+")==0){
   plus_character_handling_function();
} else if (strcmp(argv[1],"a")==0){
   a_character_handling_function();
}
```

Comment: That compares a character pointer to a character, which will not compile.

Comment: This works, but not quite :/, I was being general when I said "a" was my character, and it works wonderfully with it as it must with other characters, but the character I actually need to compare my input to is "-" and it doesn't work with it :(. Any other suggestion?

Comment: just put multiple if-else's , each one compares the argv[1] with different string, and when the result is 0 - place your handling function there

Comment: @MorgMan , Doesn't `if(strcmp(argv[1],"-")==0)printf("argv[1] is '-'");` work?

Comment: If you are just comparing **a single character**, then there is no need to waste 3 branching function calls to `strcmp` for every character you read. You can simply look at the first character in the string by dereferencing the string. (e.g. `if (*argv[1] == '-')` `else if (*argv[1] == '+')`, and so on... )

Answer (score 1):

The expression `argv[1]` is the address of a (null-terminated) array of characters.

The expression `"-"` is the address of another (null-terminated) array of characters.

These addresses are not equal, hence the expression `argv[1] == "-"` is always false.

---

That said, here is an alternative approach for checking if the input is a given character:

```
if (argv[1][0] != 0 && argv[1][1] == 0)
{
    switch (argv[1][0])
    {
    case '-':
        ...
        break;
    case '+':
        ...
        break;
    case '=':
        ...
        break;
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by doing this check:

```
argv[1] == "-";
```

you are comparing the *address* in which is contained the firrst argument of the command line, and the *address* of the literal `"-"` you have in your program, and they are different, so this is the reason your test fails. You actually want to compare the charachters contained in memory location started by these two addresses, and this is done by function of the `strcmp` family.